# In Perl, substitution operator for removing space is removing value 0 when removing space

Tags: perl

We have code where input could be either single value or comma separated value. We need to remove any spaces present before and after each value.

We are doing as below:

```
my @var_1 = split /,/,$var;
print "print_1 : @var_1 \n ";
@var_1 = grep {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $_ } @var_1;
print "print_2 : @var_1 \n ";
```

$var would contain input value. If the $var is 0 , in print_1 is printing value 0 but print_2 is printing nothing. Our requirement was just to remove spaces before and after value 0. But if the $var is 1, both print (print_1 and print_2) is correctly printing value 1. if we give input as 1,0 it is removing 0 and printing value 1 in print_2.

I am not sure why it is removing value 0. Is there any correction that can be done to substitution operator not to remove value 0 ?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I think you want to use `map`, not `grep`, but see my answer for an even simpler approach that avoids `map`/`grep` altogether.

Comment: If you care to improve your Perl, please post your full program to [codereview.se]. I've got a few words of advice for you if you want.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl, only a few distinct values are *false*. These are primarily

- `undef`
- the integer `0`
- the unsigned integer `0`
- the floating point number `0`
- the string `0`
- the empty string `""`

You've got the empty string variant and `0` here.

```
@var_1 = grep {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $_ } @var_1;
```

This code can go in three ways:

- `$_` gets cleaned up and becomes `foo`. We want it to pass.
- `$_` gets cleaned up and becomes `0`. We want it to pass.
- `$_` gets cleaned up and becomes the empty string `""`. We want it to fail.

But what happens is that because `0` is false, and `grep` only lets it through if the last statement in its block is true. That's what we want for the empty string `""`, but not for `0`.

```
@var_1 = grep {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $_ ne "" } @var_1;
```

Now that we check explicitly that the cleaned up value is not the empty string `""`, zero `0` is allowed.

Here's a complete version with cleaned up variable names (naming is important!).

```
my $input = q{foo, bar, 1 23   ,,0};
my @values = split /,/,$input;
print "print_1 : @values \n ";
@values = grep {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $_ ne q{} } @values;
print "print_2 : @values \n ";
```

The output is:

```
print_1 : foo  bar  1 23     0 
print_2 : foo bar 1 23 0
```

Note that your `grep` is not the optimal solution. As always, [there is more than one way to do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) in Perl. The `for` loop that [Сухой27 suggests in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47567927/1331451) is way more concise and I would go with that.

Comment: Funny thing is `grep {s/^\s+|\s+$//g } @var_1;` should also work due to `$_` aliasing but heavely obscures the intent.

Comment: @Сухой27 yeah. The whole idea of using `grep` to alter the value is already fundamentally flawed I believe. I only noticed that in my third time reading it. Yours is **much** cleaner.

Comment: `s///r` to the rescue. :)

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
@var_1 = map { my $v = s/^\s+|\s+$//gr; length($v) ? $v : () } @var_1
```

instead of,

```
@var_1 = grep {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $_ } @var_1;
```

`grep` is used for filtering list elements, and all false values are filtered (including `''`, `0`,  and `undef`)

Comment: This won't remove empty (whitespace-only) strings from the array. It's unclear whether the OP wants that behaviour or not.

Comment: It follows OP prog. logic and answers the question, `why 0 is filtered out`.

Comment: I'm saying that perhaps they intended `@var_1 = grep { s/^\s+|\s+$//g; length $_ } @var_1`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split on commas and removing leading and trailing whitespace from each of the resulting strings, that translates pretty literally into code:

```
my @var = map s/^\s+|\s+\z//gr, split /,/, $var, -1;
```

`/r` makes `s///` return the result of the substitution (requires perl 5.14+).  `-1` on the split is required to keep it from ignoring trailing empty fields.

If there are no zero length entries (so not e.g. `a,,b`), you can just extract what you want (sequences of non-commas that don't start or end with whitespace) directly from the string instead of first splitting it:

```
@var = $var =~ /(?!\s)[^,]+(?<!\s)/g;
```

Comment: @simbabque a challenge: see if you can come up with a `@var = $var =~ /.../g` answer that does keep empty fields; I gave up.

Comment: Wasn't removing those part of the deal?

Comment: @simbabque I saw you assumed so; I didn't see anything that indicated that, except possibly the use of grep in the first place.  I don't think that's authoritative enough

Comment: I see what you mean. Huh. I'll play around.

Comment: Also calling on @CasimiretHippolyte to take a look.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fLp8NH/1 is incredibly ugly but work. Unufortunately not in my Perl 5.24.1, because that thinks there's a variable length lookbehind.

Comment: @simbabdue `(?:(?<![^,])\s*(?=,|$)|(?!\s)[^,]+(?<!\s))` should fix that

Answer (score 1):

I suggest cleaning up the array using `map`  with a regex pattern that matches from the first to the last non-space character

There's also no need to do the `split` operation separately

Like this

```
my @var_1 = map { / ( \S (?: .* \S )? ) /x } split /,/, $var;
```

Note that this method removes empty fields. It's unclear whether that was required or not

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
@values = map {$_ =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//gr } @values;
```

or even more concise

```
@values = map {s/^\s+|\s+$//gr } @values;
```

to remove spaces in you array

Do not forget the `r` as it is the non-destructive option, otherwise you will replace your string by the number of occurences of spaces.

This said it will only work if you use Perl 5.14 or higher,
some documentation here ;)
https://www.perl.com/pub/2011/05/new-features-of-perl-514-non-destructive-substitution.html

I think this synthax is easier to understand since it is closer to the *"usual"* method of substitution.